# How to prove $\vdash p \to p$ using Hilbert axioms?

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, propositional-calculus

I am curious how one would figure out a proof like this, that $\vdash p \to p$ using only axioms and rules of inference:

https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Law_of_Identity/Formulation_2/Proof_3

Posting some details below to summarize it all:

Axiom 1 is $ \vdash A \to (B \to A)$

Axiom 2 is $\vdash (A \to (B \to C)) \to ((A \to B) \to (A \to C))$

Modus ponens is $A, (A \to B) \vdash B$

So we start with an instance of axiom 2: $(p \to ((p \to p) \to p)) \to ((p \to (p \to p)) \to (p \to p))$ where $A = p$ and $B = p \to p$ and $C = p $.

And then we have an instance of axiom 1: $p \to ((p \to p) \to p)$ where $A = p$ and $B = p \to p$.

Then using modus ponens on those two gets us $(p \to (p \to p)) \to (p \to p)$.

Now we make another instance of axiom 1: $p \to (p \to p)$ where $A = p$ and $B = p$.

Using modus ponens again with our old result and this new axiom gets us $p \to p$ and we're done.

But how would we have ever known how to figure this out? Is there a systematic way or is it mostly trial and error?

Comment: This is related to the fact that in combinator calculus, the identity combinator $I$, $I(x) = x$, can be expressed as $S~K~K$ (where $S$ is the substitution combinator $S~f~g~x = (f~x) ~ (g~x)$ and $K$ is the constant combinator $K~x~y = x$).  Though there also, you probably just need trial-and-error to come up with the combination $S~K~K$.

Comment: Can even be expressed as $S~K~Z$ where $Z$ is any combinator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We seek to prove $p\to p$, using only the three axiom schemas and modus ponens, so we need something that ultimately implies $(p\to p)$.

By inspection: Axiom 1 suggests $p\to(p\to p)$ . Axiom 2 suggests $(p\to(B\to p))\to((p\to B)\to (p\to p))$. Axiom 3 suggests $(\neg p\to\neg p)\to(p\to p)$ .

The second seems more helpful, but for what $B$?   It is trial and error time.

Substituting $B:=p$ and using modus ponens would give $(p\to p)\to(p\to p)$ which is not really helpful.

Substituting $B:=(p\to p)$ gives $(p\to((p\to p)\to p))\to((p\to(p\to p))\to(p\to p))$ which is rather helpful.   The rest falls into place.

$$\begin{array}{l}1. & p\to(p\to p) &\text{via Axiom }1\\2. & p\to((p\to p)\to p) &\text{via Axiom }1\\ 3. & (p\to((p\to p)\to p))\to((p\to(p\to p))\to(p\to p)) & \text{via Axiom }2\\ 4. & (p\to(p\to p))\to(p\to p) &\text{via modus ponens }2,3\\ 5. & p\to p &\text{via modus ponens }1,4 \\\blacksquare \end{array}$$

---

So trial and error is involved, but a systematic approach is needed. Pattern recognition skills are quite essential.

Answer (score 4):

I would say it is mostly accidental that this combination of axioms works to produce $p\to p$. (In comments, Daniel Schleper pointed out a relation to combinator calculus, but it is doubtful whether that should be called an explanation, or just the same accident expressed in a different language).

In fact, it is not uncommon to present Hilbert-style systems with $A\to A$ included as an *axiom* because the author doesn't want to confuse students with this proof that is not particularly intuitively meaningful.

Once you do have $A\to A$ and your axioms 1 and 2, things start being easier because those three axioms are exactly what you need to prove the *Deduction Theorem*. From that point on, proof construction becomes more natural -- since you can now think mostly in terms of *Natural Deduction* rather than the pure combinatory glory of the Hilbert system.

Comment: I do not think it is accidental at all, since the calculus was deviced with very specific goals in mind.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo: What I'm saying is that I think those very specific goals did _not_ include "the tautology we use for an assumption must be derivable from the tautology we use for an axiom and the tautology we use for modus ponens".

Comment: I understand. I am saying that I actually think the opposite was the case.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo: So you think someone was thinking: "I want to declare two of the three tautologies I need for the Deduction Theorem to be axions, and I want the third one to be a consequence of the two others"?

Comment: I think a lot of thought of the kind we  now call reverse engineering went into the choice of axioms; that much, I imagine you agree with as well. I understand you disagree with the details of what I believe that entailed.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Could you perhaps be made to reveal _which_ "very specific goals" it is you contend that made someone design the Deduction Theorem such that the axioms that are necessary for two of the inductive cases happen to imply the axiom that is necessary for the third inductive case?

Comment: "Be made to reveal" what I "contend"... Any reason why you are being so aggressive, Henning? If the tone of my comments invites such an off-putting reply, I apologize as that was not my intention.

Comment: @AndrésE.Caicedo Sorry for the tone. But I really cannot understand how it is you think this fact _could conceivably_ have been designed rather than just something that happens to happen as a byproduct of achieving other goals, and I'm trying to get you to explain how that would work.

Comment: Thank you. I expect two of the earliest goals of any such axiomatization were independence and completeness. Perhaps not quite in the sense we understand these notions today (not quite semantic completeness yet, for instance) but rather functional completeness and a kind of functional independence. There is probably more nuance to add here, but I must leave now.

Comment: I read somewhere that Schonfinkel was one of Hilbert's students, and so it is possible that Hilbert knew that identity followed from the other two rules.

Answer (score 0):

> But how would we have ever known how to figure this out? Is there a systematic way or is it mostly trial and error?

There exists a meta-theorem in propositional calculus, discovered by J. A. Kalman, that every theorem that can get proved by substitution and detachment can get can get proved by condensed detachment or is a substitution instance of a theorem provable by condensed detachment.

Systematically, (p$\rightarrow$p) can get derived in 2 condensed detachments.  Thus, the proof could have systematically got discovered first by doing two condensed detachments, then writing out a substitution and detachment proof from using that deduction, and then pushing back all substitutions to the axioms.

The process works as follows in Polish notation.

```
axiom 1 CpCqp
axiom 2 CCpCqrCCpqCpr
D2.1  3 CCpqCpp
D3.1  4 Cpp
```

Now we'll write out a substitution and detachment proof, allowing substitution in theorems:

```
axiom  1 CpCqp
axiom  2 CCpCqrCCpqCpr
from 2 3 CCpCqpCCpqCpp
{3, 1} 4 CCpqCpp
from 4 5 CCpCqpCpp
{5, 1} 6 Cpp
```

Now we just pushback all of the substitutions to the axioms:

```
axiom  1 CpCqp
axiom  2 CCpCqrCCpqCpr
from 2 3 CCpCCpppCCpCppCpp
from 1 4 CpCCppp
{4, 3} 5 CCpCppCpp
from 1 6 CpCpp
{5, 6} 7 Cpp
```