# Equivalence in propositional axioms

Tags: propositional-calculus, first-order-logic

I am following Lou van den Dries' Mathematical Logic notes where he introduces some of the propositional axioms as follows:

A1) $\top$

A2) $p \to (p \vee q) \ ; \ p \to (q \vee p)$

...

A6) $(p \to (q \to r)) \to ((p \to q) \to (p \to r))$

...

Then he shows a proof of $\vdash p \to p$ using the proposition $p \to ((p \to p) \to p)$ as an instance of axiom scheme 2 and then uses axiom scheme 6 and Modus Ponens to finish the proof. Why is that instance of axiom scheme 2 valid? My professor said that he expressed $p \vee q$ in scheme 2 as and adquate proposition using $\to$. Is this really valid?

If so can I also use other equivalences like De Morgan's Laws? And if not how could $\vdash p \to p$ be proved using strictly the axiom schemes that van den Dries gives?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe that's a typo, either in A2 or in the argument.  It's usual in Hilbert-type systems (exactly the same systems where A6 typically pops up) to have an axiom of the form $p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow p)$.  And $p \rightarrow ((p \rightarrow p) \rightarrow p)$ would indeed be a specialization of that axiom $p \rightarrow (q \rightarrow p)$.

Comment: In the second part of axiom scheme 2 take $q=\neg(p\rightarrow p)$. I assume the author has already defined $a \rightarrow b$ as $\neg a \lor b$

Comment: @Sam - yes; it is so defined at page 15.

Comment: @Sam's comment is correct : form $p \to (q \lor p)$ to $p \to (\lnot q \lor p)$ [substitution] to $p \to (q \to p)$ [abbreviation] to $p \to ((p \to p) \to p)$ [substitution].

Comment: [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2923329/how-to-prove-vdash-p-to-p-using-hilbert-axioms) is a proof with a slightly different system of axioms.